# Is there a way to test "Turing completeness"?

Tags: computability, computation-models, turing-completeness

I asked my algorithms teacher today the very same question that is stated in the title, but he seemed a bit unsure, either on the question or on the concept, so I thought I'd try here too.

Is there a minimal test that could determine whether a language or instruction set is Turing compete, or does a test of that sort fall into the domain of undecidability?

It might seem like a trivial or stupid question, but the reason I ask is that it would be a good way to test whether the instructions of a cellular automaton is Turing complete, and if there is such a test, maybe it could help when generating cellular automata.

I'm quite new to both cellular automata and undecidability problems, so go easy on me.

Comment: What do you mean by "test"? How is the language or instruction set represented?

Comment: I meant "test" a bit fluidly, like in "is there a way to determine". I guess that a test could either be some external test (algorithm/procedure) working on a instruction set, or a way to use parts of a arbitrary instruction set to translate into some kind of minimal proof of Turing completeness.

Comment: One way to determine that something *is* Turing-complete is to create a Turing machine emulator with it.

Comment: @immibis *And* it must be emulatable on a Turing machine. There is no proof whether there are Turing-powerful models of computation that are not Turing-complete.

Comment: @Rhymoid "In computability theory, a system of data-manipulation rules (such as a computer's instruction set, a programming language, or a cellular automaton) is said to be Turing complete or computationally universal if it can be used to simulate any single-taped Turing machine." - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness), see also the "Formal definitions" section.

Comment: @immibis I know. Except that "computationally universal" is a presumptious title, as there is no proof that there isn't anything 'stronger' (i.e. a model of computation that can simulate any TM, but which can't be simulated by any TM).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/449014/10396

Comment: @Rhymoid Your comments seem to imply that Turing-complete means a system that can simulate all TMs and be simulated by a TM, but this is not the case. Turing-completeness refer only to the first part: a system is Turing-complete if it can simulate all TMs, period. It **can** be stronger than a TM, so I don't see your point.

Comment: @Bakuriu That is my understanding, in analogy of the nomenclature of other sorts of classes like "NP-complete".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know about specific models. It's pretty easy to become Turing Complete, since all you need is infinite search. So I can imagine a model where searching for finite vs. infiniteness boils down to Turing Completeness, but I don't know if any actually exist.

But a general algorithm "look at an arbitrary systems and tell if it's Turing Complete" can't exist. Otherwise we could do this:

```
RunTuringMachine = lambda (M1) . lambda (x). lambda (M2) . 
  run M1 on x and discard the result
  run M2 //we only get to this line if M1 halts on x
```

Then, for any inputs M1, x, `RunTuringMachine M1 x` is a Turing-complete system if and only if `M1` halts on input `x`, and we've solved the halting problem.

We could also prove this by Rice's theorem: if we can decide if any system is Turing Complete, then we can decide of a Turing Machine is a Universal Turing Machine, which is impossible by Rice's Theorem.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense, however, showing that an instruction set can do infinite search seems like a problem that could also be a undecidable one. I found something called "cyclic tag system" that seems to have history of proving Turing completeness of cellular automata.

Comment: This is a weirdly artificial counterexample. It's basically, If M1 halts given x, run known Turing Machine; else, do nothing. I also doubt its correctness, the line: "if (M1 halts running on x)" is quite dubious because of the halting problem. In other words, you've assumed you have a general solution to the halting problem. So I think all this really proves is that, if the halting problem has a solution then it's impossible to tell if an arbitrary system is Turing complete. Then this proof is vacuous since you've started from a false hypothesis. (p->q) is always true if p is false.

Comment: @user2264247 It's not a counter-example, it's a reduction, so specific or not, you only need one to prove something undecidable. The "if M1 halts running on x" is basically just a way to say "run M1 on x, and do the following if it halts". Obviously we'll never hit the `loop` line. But the important thing is, we never actually run this code, we just use it as an input to the hypothetical "is this system Turing Complete" algorithm, deriving a contradiction to disprove its existence.

Comment: @user2264247 I've fixed it to not explicitly call a halting problem solver. But you should review [Rice's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), its proofs look basically like this.

Answer (score 4):

Is there an **automatic** test for Turing Completeness? I'm not sure. I'm going to guess not since it feels like an analog of the halting problem.

Is there a way for **humans** to tell if a system is Turing Complete? Yes.

It all boils down to the [Church-Turing thesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis). The TLDR version is that two systems can solve the same set of problems if they can run emulators of each other.

So one way to prove that a system is Turing complete is to emulate a universal Turing machine. The [game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) for example was proven to be Turing complete by emulating a [universal Turing machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=My8AsV7bA94).

> Side note: An actual Turing machine has infinite tape length. Therefore no physical system is technically Turing complete (at minimum the universe has a maximum number of electrons). The usual caveat goes something like: this CPU/programming language is Turing complete if we assume infinite memory.

Comment: Nitpicking: You don't need **infinite** memory. You need **unbounded** memory.